# Express rest and sequelize - complex nested query. need advice

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, jwt, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize and inside a project I have three models:

```
Project({name: String}), 
Task({name: String}),
TaskCategory({name: String})

Project.hasMany(Task)
Task.belongsTo(TaskCategory)
```

I need to create a query that returns something like this:

GET /api/projects/:id

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Project 1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "task 1",
      "category": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "category 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "task 2",
      "category": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "category 1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "taskCount": "2",
  "taskCountPerCategory": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "category": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "category 1"
      },
      "count": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "category": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "category 2"
      },
      "count": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "category": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "category 3"
      },
      "count": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "category": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "category 4"
      },
      "count": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm really stuck with this. I know I can do something like this:

```
Project.find({
    where: {id: 1}, 
    include: [{model: Task, include: [{model: TaskCategory}]}]
})
```

But I'm lost with the "taskCount", "taskCountPerCategory" parts.

Please note that "taskCountPerCategory" should retrieve task count per each TaskCategory in the system.